# Memcached 1.4.15 build fails on Cygwin using gcc 4.5.3

Tags: memcached, cygwin

I have not been able to successfully build and test memcached 1.4.15 on Cygwin as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869655/building-memcached-1-4-x-on-windows-error-with-cygwin). I was able to build after the 3 fixes, one for removal of the `-Werror` CFLAG from the Makefile, second for the `sanitytest` casting to int and the third for the `testapp.c` code changes as [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869655/building-memcached-1-4-x-on-windows-error-with-cygwin). However, when I run the `testapp.exe` I get the following output :

```
$ ./testapp.exe
1..47
ok 1 - cache_create
ok 2 - cache_constructor
ok 3 - cache_constructor_fail
ok 4 - cache_destructor
ok 5 - cache_reuse
ok 6 - cache_redzone
ok 7 - issue_161
ok 8 - strtol
ok 9 - strtoll
ok 10 - strtoul
ok 11 - strtoull
ok 12 - issue_44
ok 13 - vperror
```

And after killing the daemon processes (`testrun.exe` and `memcached-debug.exe`) which get triggered as a part of the run of the testapp, I started the memcached executable in daemon mode(`-d`) and with verbose console output (`-vv`), here is the output i see :

**Server (Cygwin bash shell):**

```
<24 server listening (udp)
<24 server listening (udp)
<25 new auto-negotiating client connection
25: Client using the ascii protocol
<25 stats
Failed to write, and not due to blocking: Address family not supported by protocol
<25 connection closed.
```

**Client (MS-DOS command prompt):**

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

My local environment is:-
Windows 7 x64
Cygwin
gcc 4.5.3
libevent2.0.20-stable
memcached1.4.15

Can someone please help me fix this ? 
Thanks in advance..